# issues sendgrid for email messaging

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I an using sendgrid for email messaging but get the error below. My code is below the error.

```
Error:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes3.dex)
                          at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
                          at
```

**Email Messaging code:**

```
Email from = new Email("zihronProjectManagementApp@gmail.com");

    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";

    Email to = new Email("ayobami.o.idowu@gmail.com");

    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");

    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),System.getenv('"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"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("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"));

    Request request = new Request();

    try {

        request.setMethod(Method.POST);

        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");

        request.setBody(mail.build());

        Response response = sg.api(request);

        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());

        System.out.println(response.getBody());

        System.out.println(response.getHeaders());

    } catch (IOException ex) {


    }
```

I have tried every possible post on Stack Overflow. Please help me in what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier
```

Above class has been removed API level 22

You should use [HttpURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#behavior-apache-http-client) class instead.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to implement HttpURLConnection class in android gradle?

Comment: @XingTimisencoGenesis I don't know if your problem has been resolved or not, or whether you still need solution or not. But there's actually someone who modify Sendgrid plugin into using HttpURLConnection. Look at the plugin here: https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android