# Sendgrid Android plugin init error "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type .../AllowAllHostnameVerifier"

Tags: android, sendgrid

I'm trying the Sendgrid plugin API for Android. I'm following the step on Sendgrid website, which ends with:

```
import com.sendgrid.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
    String subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
    Email to = new Email("test@example.com");
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with Java");
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

    SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
    Request request = new Request();
    try {
      request.setMethod(Method.POST);
      request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
      request.setBody(mail.build());
      Response response = sg.api(request);
      System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(response.getBody());
      System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

This code produce error on:

```
SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
```

of:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:966)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
        at com.sendgrid.Client.<init>(Client.java:56)
        at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:52)
        ...
```

From [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52319212/3003927), I discovered that `AllowAllHostnameVerifier` has been deprecated since API v22. But I don't have enough knowledge in Android to be able to toying around with third party library and change it into HTTPUrlConnection.

I also stumble upon [this sendgrid library](https://github.com/danysantiago/sendgrid-android) that change that particular networking library to Http library, but when I tried to run, I got tons of "duplicate class" error between httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1) and httpcore-4.3.2.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2).

How can I resolve or work around this problem? I have used the latest Sendgrid plugins (4.4.1), and the same problem still popped up.